# Magento2.3 - Fatal error: allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes

Tags: magento2.3, php-7.2, memory-limit

Migrate from one server to another server.

I have a big problem with this because I cannot understand the logic on it.
`Magento 2.3.2 and php 7.2`

`Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in /public_html/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/Config/Placeholder.php on line 146`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please make sure both fields secure and unsecure base_url are filled with proper value.

May be you are directly adding the incorrect value to core_config_data. Magento cannot parse it, and it causes an infinite recursion. If you want to remove some value from core_config_data, you should delete the whole record, not only it's "value" raw.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, for one of my websites urls from `web/secure/base_url` and `web/unsecure/base_url` values were set to `null` from the **core_config_data** table and I didn't get any errors until i have put in top of the `pub/index.php` file, this:

```
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

By setting it to have a value or remove the records. It fixed the issue.